# Wrap border around contained text

Tags: html, css, width, border

With the below code, it allows for a "code block" for code to stand out on. Is there a way that I can wrap, but not too tightly (20px border maybe?) the box around the text within? And related, is there a way to limit how far the code on the inside can go before being wrapped to the next line? This would allow me to limit the size of the code block to be 1000px

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cxxDC/)

HTML

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Sample Wiki Page</TITLE>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type = 'text/css' href = 'default.css' />
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <DIV id='content'>
            <h3>Main Title</h3>
            <h2>Sub Title</h2>
                <p>
                     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi eros odio, venenatis ut suscipit eget, vestibulum id est. Vivamus aliquet lacus sit amet enim tempus in fermentum ipsum ornare. Pellentesque tincidunt orci sed sem luctus tristique. Ut a turpis ac nisi semper luctus. Nulla mattis ornare augue, vel lacinia purus porta eu. Vestibulum pulvinar justo dolor, in ultricies tellus. Nullam semper, ante at feugiat commodo, neque eros pulvinar ante, et porttitor velit orci eu magna. Duis mattis libero vitae magna lacinia tincidunt. Vivamus placerat elit a nisi ultrices elementum. Vestibulum condimentum posuere nulla, id ornare urna mattis id. Quisque ornare risus diam. Nunc malesuada leo sit amet mauris bibendum pharetra. Integer convallis orci id lorem volutpat suscipit.

                    Vestibulum ac magna libero, non condimentum neque. Integer vestibulum, quam at tempus fermentum, mi odio dictum nibh, quis venenatis velit ligula laoreet massa. Fusce lobortis augue eu ante bibendum consequat eget posuere neque. Mauris dui lorem, fringilla et auctor a, eleifend id nisi. Sed nunc tortor, blandit et malesuada quis, posuere pellentesque lorem. Nunc vehicula lectus eget tortor tempus sed pharetra diam luctus. Aenean odio leo, accumsan a vestibulum ut, tincidunt in mi. Curabitur commodo venenatis dolor, ultrices placerat nibh tempor nec. Duis eget odio mi, id imperdiet lectus. Aenean luctus bibendum arcu non egestas.
                </p>
            <h2>Code Section</h2>
            <pre>
                <xmp>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Sample Wiki Page</TITLE>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type = 'text/css' href = 'default.css' />
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <h3>Main Title</h3>
        <h2>Sub Title</h2>
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi eros odio, venenatis ut
             suscipit eget, vestibulum id est. Vivamus aliquet lacus sit amet enim tempus in fermentum 
             ipsum ornare. Pellentesque tincidunt orci sed sem luctus tristique. Ut a turpis ac nisi 
             semper luctus. Nulla mattis ornare augue, vel lacinia purus porta eu. Vestibulum pulvinar 
             justo dolor, in ultricies tellus. Nullam semper, ante at feugiat commodo, neque eros 
             pulvinar ante, et porttitor velit orci eu magna. Duis mattis libero vitae magna lacinia 
             tincidunt. Vivamus placerat elit a nisi ultrices elementum. Vestibulum condimentum posuere 
             nulla, id ornare urna mattis id. Quisque ornare risus diam. Nunc malesuada leo sit amet 
             mauris bibendum pharetra. Integer convallis orci id lorem volutpat suscipit.

            Vestibulum ac magna libero, non condimentum neque. Integer vestibulum, quam at tempus 
            fermentum, mi odio dictum nibh, quis venenatis velit ligula laoreet massa. Fusce lobortis 
            augue eu ante bibendum consequat eget posuere neque. Mauris dui lorem, fringilla et auctor 
            a, eleifend id nisi. Sed nunc tortor, blandit et malesuada quis, posuere pellentesque lorem
            . Nunc vehicula lectus eget tortor tempus sed pharetra diam luctus. Aenean odio leo, 
            accumsan a vestibulum ut, tincidunt in mi. Curabitur commodo venenatis dolor, ultrices 
            placerat nibh tempor nec. Duis eget odio mi, id imperdiet lectus. Aenean luctus bibendum 
            arcu non egestas.
        <h2>Code Section</h2>
        <pre>
        </pre>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
            </xmp>
            </pre>
        </DIV>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

CSS

```
#content pre {
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px dashed #2f6fab;
    color: black;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    white-space: pre;
    margin: 1em 0px;
    display: block;
    font-family: monospace,Courier;
    line-height: 1.1em;
    width:70%;
}

#content h3{
    font-size: 188%;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    color: black;
    background: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: .5em;
    padding-bottom: .17em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
    margin-bottom: 1.2em;
}
#content h1, h2 {
    color: black;
    background: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: .5em;
    padding-bottom: .17em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
    width: 40%;
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific when you say stuff like "box" or "code". It helps if you explain what class, or id, you're talking about, and around what content/code you're trying to apply it to.

Comment: added fiddle to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `white-space: pre-wrap;` to the `xmp` tag.

Comment: gotta wait 10 minutes after asking the question

Answer (score 0):

I believe the xmp tag has been deprecated for a while. You should encode your text to convert the 'illegal' characters into html-entities. Many IDE's provide this functionality, or you could use some script or a online tool.

Also, when you use the pre tag, it is not possible make line-breaks automatic, that is exactly what the pre is for.

I suggest you alter your approach and have a look at something like this: http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/

This way can also have the benefits of code coloring etc.